# Trying to get rid of this error : cannot allocate vector of size 500 mb

Tags: r, memory-management, garbage-collection, data.table, sqldf

Tried `gc()`, increasing `memory.limit()`, nothing seems to work. Using 64 bit R. The data.frame `df` has 32 million rows and is approximately 4 GB in size; df2 is relatively small. I have removed all variables from the global environment, apart from df and df2. The error appears after the line of `sqldf` code below.

Could anyone help me with the equivalent of this code in the data.table package, to see if using that resolves the stack overflow:

```
df <- sqldf(
  'select A.*, 
  case when A.cost is null then B.meancost else A.cost end imputedcost 
  from df A 
  left join df2 B on A.ID = B.ID'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're trying to use `sqldf` for manipulation here because df and df2 are quite large, as 500 mb should not be enough to cause a stack overflow on its own. Two possibilities jump out:

- You've got lots of other data in memory currently (df and df2 might be very large)
- The left join of df and df2 is gobbling up more memory than the error is indicating

Possible solutions:

- Replace the left join with something more memory-friendly. Is meancost variable within table B, or static? i.e. Could that just be a number?
- Try doing this transformation using data.table instead of sqldf. sqldf is not terribly fast computationally at this kind of work, which suggests it might be less efficient memory-wise.
- Break the datasets up into smaller pieces, so R can fit it all in memory
- Make these transformations in an actual SQL environment designed to handle large data transformations, rather than R where everything is stored in memory. You can use PostgreSQL to interact with the SQL environment through R, if you prefer.

Here's how I might approach this with data.table:

```
# Set up data.tables
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(df)
df2 <- as.data.table(df2)

# Combine, just selecting the necessary columns from df2
df <- data.table::merge.data.table(df, df2[, .(ID, meancost)], by = "ID", all.x = T)

# Set imputed cost conditional on cost existing
df[, imputedcost := cost]
df[is.na(cost) | is.null(cost), imputedcost := meancost]

# Remove the meancost column
df[, meancost := NULL]
```

Comment: Thanks.I have removed  all the other variables from global env apart from df and df2,still I get this error .

Comment: You can use `object.size()` to see exactly how large df and df2 are. I suspect they are consuming most of R's available memory, and you will need to load them into PostgreSQL or similar to manipulate them as a whole with your available memory. The other option would be to break them into smaller pieces (only read in half the lines at a time, for example).

Comment: When I tried to run your code it says : 'merge' is not an exported object from 'namespace:data.table'

Comment: Size of df : 4020986780,size of df2: 8964578

Comment: You may need `data.table::merge.data.table()`; updated answer.

If I'm reading that correctly, you've got a 4GB df object, which when joined to df2 is becoming even larger. That's probably the culprit; either break the dataset into smaller components or use an external database.

Comment: I think I won't be be able to use an external db as df and df2 have gone through some rigourous data cleaning in previous steps

Comment: Thanks I got rid of the error through data.table package .Have one doubt in your code in the way it's joined. Is it the same as left join in the code I  wrote

Comment: Yes, the `all.x. = T` argument is effectively a left join. It will keep all observations from `df` regardless of whether they match one in `df2`.

Answer (score 1):

`sqldf` uses an in-memory data base by default but you can ask it to use an external database via the following.

There is nothing you have to set up. It does it all. Just add `dbname = tempfile()` to your `sqldf` statement.

```
sqldf(...whatever..., dbname = tempfile())
```

The following won't make any difference to memory usage but as an aside note that you can write this query as:

```
sqldf('select A.*, coalesce(A.cost, B.meancost) as newcost
  from df A
  left join df2 B using(ID)`)
```